# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException cannot intent to another java

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

When i press the button login, it must move to another activity by using intent.

My logcat:

```
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{a.cibi/a.cibi.home_spv}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at a.cibi.home_spv.<init>(home_spv.java:12)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-28 00:23:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3563):     ... 11 more
```

As you can see above i am getting Android: java.lang.NullPointerException which is the main reason.

And open file:

```
Activity.Thread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line:2137
that contain "Source Not Found"
```

My mainactivity.java is:

```
package a.cibi;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Gravity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.PopupWindow;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            AstraDB b = new AstraDB(this);
            public String status1;
            Button BtnClosePopup;
            Button BtnCreatePopup;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.login);
                b.open();
                /*
                String abc = b.getLastSalesman().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "aaaaa"+abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(abc.equals("NotExist")){
                    long id;
                    id = b.insertStaff(12345, "Novie", "astra1", "123456", "novie@a.id", "SPV");
                    id = b.insertSalesman("23456", "Erlien", "astra2", "123", "erlien@a.id", "Retail");
                    id = b.insertDealer("1111", "Berlian", "Erlien", "Jakarta Barat", "12234", "Retail");
                    id = b.insertDealer("1112", "intan", "Erlien", "Jakarta Barat", "12234", "Retail");
                    id = b.insertDealer("1113", "emas", "Erlien", "Jakarta Barat", "12234", "Retail");
                    id = b.insertDealer("1114", "perak", "Erlien", "Jakarta Barat", "12234", "Retail");
                    String abcd = b.getLastSalesman().toString();
                    if(!abcd.equals("NotExist")){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data telah masuk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                */
                final EditText etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUser);
                final EditText etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPass);

                Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
                bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        boolean a = false;

                        String userName = etUser.getText().toString();
                        String userPass = etPass.getText().toString();
                        //b.open();
                        String storedPasswordStaff = b.getStaff(userName);
                        String storedPasswordSales = b.getSalesman(userName);

                        if(userPass.equals(storedPasswordSales))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome, Salesman NPK: "+userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            a = true;
                            status1="Salesman";
                        }
                        else if(a==false){
                            if(userPass.equals(storedPasswordStaff)){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome, Staff NPK: "+userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                a = true;
                                status1="Staff";
                            }
                        }
                        if(a==true){
                            if(status1.equals("Salesman")){
                                startPopupWindow();
                                Intent z= new Intent(MainActivity.this, home_salesman.class);
                                z.putExtra("status", status1);
                                z.putExtra("NPK", userName);
                                startActivity(z);
                            }
                            else if (status1.equals("Staff")){
                                Intent z= new Intent(MainActivity.this, home_spv.class);
                                z.putExtra("status", status1);
                                z.putExtra("NPK", userName);
                                startActivity(z);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    private PopupWindow popwin;
                    private void startPopupWindow()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_visit,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_popup));

                            popwin = new PopupWindow(layout, 700, 950, true);
                            popwin.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                            BtnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
                            BtnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_listener);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    //function ngeclose window
                        private OnClickListener cancel_listener = new OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                popwin.dismiss();   
                            }
                        };
                });
                };
        }
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a.cibi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".home_spv"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".home_salesman"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my home_spv.java:

```
       package a.cibi;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class home_spv extends Activity {
    AstraDB b = new AstraDB(this);
    String Statuss, userName;
    String tampNama="aa";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_spv);
        Statuss = getIntent().getExtras().getString("status");
        userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NPK");
        Button UpdateProfile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.UpdateProfile);
        Button RegisterSalesman = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RegisterSalesman);
        Button SPVRolling = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SPVRolling);
        TextView welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomespv);
        tampNama = b.getNamaStaff(userName).toString();
        welcome.setText("Selamat datang, "+tampNama+" !");
        UpdateProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent z= new Intent(home_spv.this, Update_Profile.class);
                z.putExtra("status", Statuss);
                z.putExtra("NPK", userName);
                startActivity(z);
            }
        });
        RegisterSalesman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent z= new Intent(home_spv.this, RegisterSales.class);
                z.putExtra("status", Statuss);
                z.putExtra("NPK", userName);
                startActivity(z);
            }
        });
        SPVRolling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent z= new Intent(home_spv.this, SPV_Rolling.class);
                z.putExtra("status", Statuss);
                z.putExtra("NPK", userName);
                startActivity(z);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I already use two types of method to getStaffName that works in different classes, but not work in this class:

```
public Cursor getNamaStaff(String staffNPK)throws SQLException{
        Cursor cur = db.query(Staff_TABLE, new String[] 
                {Col_StaffNPK, Col_StaffName}, Col_StaffNPK +"="+ staffNPK, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cur!=null){
            cur.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cur;
    }


    public String getNamaStaff(String staffNPK)
    {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(Staff_TABLE, null, ""+Col_StaffNPK+"=?", new String[]{staffNPK}, null, null,null);

        if(mCursor.getCount()<1){
            mCursor.close();
            return "Not Exist";
        }
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Col_StaffName));
        mCursor.close();
        return password;    
    }
```

Comment: post the entire logcat

Comment: error  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo means there is a one field which you are trying to call from JAVA that was not exists in XML. please check you xml once

Comment: @Android he is getting NPE

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya yes you are right but in his question he mentioned something like ComponentInfo also.. if he post the xml and log only we can give some suggestions..

Comment: @panini i already edit questions with full log cat

Comment: @novie please also post home_spv.java

Comment: also post line at home_spv.java:12

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya the home_spv.java:12 is String Statuss = getIntent().getExtras().getString("status");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these initializations to `onCreate()`:

```
String Statuss = getIntent().getExtras().getString("status");
String userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NPK");
```

When the object is created, `getIntent()` will return `null`.

Comment: So what should i do? I already move the getIntent after the oncreate() but still didnt work

Comment: Not after but inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: Where's the code that sets up the `home_spv` intent? It's possible that there are no extras, either.

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya already. i guess there's something error with tampNama=b.getNamaStaff

Comment: @novie replace `getIntent().getExtras().getString("status");` by `getIntent().getStringExtra("status");` for both status and NPK

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya already change the code but still cannot work. i edit the question with the method .getNamaStaff

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! Forgot to open the database.. >.< THANK YOU EVERYONEE!!